# Laravel Auto-Link library

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autolink

I'm looking for a travel auto-link detection.

I'm trying to make a social media website and when my users post URLs I need it so like shows instead of just normal text.

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you saying you have a chunk of text and you need to work out if there are links in it? How about Regexs to search for  `http`, `www.`, etc?

Comment: So i have the posts from the users in my database. The users can post anything like links, text etc and im wanting the urls that they post to turn into links when they are displayed on the newsfeed

Answer (score 0):

Try [Autologin for Laravel](https://github.com/dwightwatson/autologin) by **dwightwatson**, which provides you to generate URLs that will provide automatic login to your application and then redirect to the appropriate location

Comment: I dont need a link top autologin. i need a way to turn urls in text to links that people post to the site

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no equivalent in the Laravel's core for the auto_link() funtion helper from Code Igniter (assuming you are refering to the CI version).

Anyway, it's very simple to grab that code and use it in Laravel for a quick an dirty workaround. I just did casually looking for the same issue.

Put in your App directory a container class for your helpers (or any containter for the matter, it's just need to be discovered by the framework), in this case I put a UrlHelpers.php file. Then, inside of it put this two static functions grabbed for the CI version:

```
class UrlHelpers
{
    static function auto_link($str, $type = 'both', $popup = FALSE)
    {
        // Find and replace any URLs.
        if ($type !== 'email' && preg_match_all('#(\w*://|www\.)[^\s()<>;]+\w#i', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
            // Set our target HTML if using popup links.
            $target = ($popup) ? ' target="_blank"' : '';

            // We process the links in reverse order (last -> first) so that
            // the returned string offsets from preg_match_all() are not
            // moved as we add more HTML.
            foreach (array_reverse($matches) as $match) {
                // $match[0] is the matched string/link
                // $match[1] is either a protocol prefix or 'www.'
                //
                // With PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, both of the above is an array,
                // where the actual value is held in [0] and its offset at the [1] index.
                $a = '<a href="' . (strpos($match[1][0], '/') ? '' : 'http://') . $match[0][0] . '"' . $target . '>' . $match[0][0] . '</a>';
                $str = substr_replace($str, $a, $match[0][1], strlen($match[0][0]));
            }
        }

        // Find and replace any emails.
        if ($type !== 'url' && preg_match_all('#([\w\.\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.[a-z0-9\-\.]+[^[:punct:]\s])#i', $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
            foreach (array_reverse($matches[0]) as $match) {
                if (filter_var($match[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== FALSE) {
                    $str = substr_replace($str, static::safe_mailto($match[0]), $match[1], strlen($match[0]));
                }
            }
        }

        return $str;
    }

    static function safe_mailto($email, $title = '', $attributes = '')
    {
        $title = (string)$title;

        if ($title === '') {
            $title = $email;
        }

        $x = str_split('<a href="mailto:', 1);

        for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($email); $i < $l; $i++) {
            $x[] = '|' . ord($email[$i]);
        }

        $x[] = '"';

        if ($attributes !== '') {
            if (is_array($attributes)) {
                foreach ($attributes as $key => $val) {
                    $x[] = ' ' . $key . '="';
                    for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($val); $i < $l; $i++) {
                        $x[] = '|' . ord($val[$i]);
                    }
                    $x[] = '"';
                }
            } else {
                for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($attributes); $i < $l; $i++) {
                    $x[] = $attributes[$i];
                }
            }
        }

        $x[] = '>';

        $temp = array();
        for ($i = 0, $l = strlen($title); $i < $l; $i++) {
            $ordinal = ord($title[$i]);

            if ($ordinal < 128) {
                $x[] = '|' . $ordinal;
            } else {
                if (count($temp) === 0) {
                    $count = ($ordinal < 224) ? 2 : 3;
                }

                $temp[] = $ordinal;
                if (count($temp) === $count) {
                    $number = ($count === 3)
                        ? (($temp[0] % 16) * 4096) + (($temp[1] % 64) * 64) + ($temp[2] % 64)
                        : (($temp[0] % 32) * 64) + ($temp[1] % 64);
                    $x[] = '|' . $number;
                    $count = 1;
                    $temp = array();
                }
            }
        }

        $x[] = '<';
        $x[] = '/';
        $x[] = 'a';
        $x[] = '>';

        $x = array_reverse($x);

        $output = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n"
            . "\t//<![CDATA[\n"
            . "\tvar l=new Array();\n";

        for ($i = 0, $c = count($x); $i < $c; $i++) {
            $output .= "\tl[" . $i . "] = '" . $x[$i] . "';\n";
        }

        $output .= "\n\tfor (var i = l.length-1; i >= 0; i=i-1) {\n"
            . "\t\tif (l[i].substring(0, 1) === '|') document.write(\"&#\"+unescape(l[i].substring(1))+\";\");\n"
            . "\t\telse document.write(unescape(l[i]));\n"
            . "\t}\n"
            . "\t//]]>\n"
            . '</script>';

        return $output;
    }

}
```

The function safe_mailto is used in case there are email links in your string. If you don't need it you are free to modify the code.

Then you could use the helper class like this in any part of your Laravel code as usually (here inside a blade template, but the principle is the same):

```
<p>{!! \App\Helpers\Helpers::auto_link($string) !!}</p>
```

Quick and dirty, and It works. Hope to have helped. ¡Good luck!